# How to define Outlets and Actions in the Classes Pane in Interface Builder in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, interface-builder, xcode4

In Xcode 3 one used to be able to define Outlets, Actions etc in Interface Builder by going to the Library > Classes Pane and selecting the class from the list. Is this functionality missing in Xcode 4 ?

[image]

There is a File Template Library in the Utility area (Lower Right Corner) in Xcode 4 but my custom clases do not show here !!

Comment: I think they may have taken that functionality out because it is more common to define outlets and actions in the `.h` file, and in Xcode 4 using the split assistant editor view, you can easily create these by control-dragging controls to the `.h` editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does appear to be removed from Xcode 4, but there isn't much need for it anymore since Xcode 4 integrates the editor directly with IB. The feature never really worked that well in Xcode 3 IMO anyway.

In Xcode 4, display the header for your object by selecting your object and View>Editors>Assistant. Now control-drag from the object you want to connect into the header. This will let you automatically create an outlet or action and bind it all at once.

See the [Xcode 4 Transition Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html) for more information.

Comment: How do I go about this if I want to edit code files separately in my editor of choice and only define the xib in Xcode?

Comment: By setting up the IBOutlets in Xcode as described. Other times you may edit wherever you like, but this step is about editing the xib file.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I don't have the .h or .m files listed in xcode, just the nibs. I would like to edit code in sublime, and onlu edit the interface in Xcode.

Comment: This is not an option. Add the .h and .m files to Xcode. You may edit them anywhere you like, but they must be in the project so that Xcode can create nib file connections. (Also, how do you build this project without telling Xcode where the files are?)

Comment: Easy, I don't build with Xcode, I have my own makefile with something like this:

cc -Wall -arch x86_64 -fobjc-arc -O2 -framework Cocoa -framework AppKit -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGL src/mac/*.m -o myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp        
   
ibtool --compile myapp.app/Contents/Resources/Application.nib src/mac/Application.xib

Comment: If you fight the tools this much, it should not be surprising that the tools become hard to use… You should use `xcodebuild` to perform commandline builds, not `make`. It'll handle all of this for you, while still allowing you to use any editor you like.

Comment: I just don't like drag-drop programming. I tried adding controls in the code itself, but gave up after realising I needed 15 lines of code to make a textfield look like a label, and it still didn't look right. I thought I could create nibs without loading the whole code base into xcode. I guess apple knows best. I'll try to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

agreed with Rob on that, alternative is to right click your Object in xcode's IB and this will give allow you to select actions/reference etc by means of dragging and dropping

Comment: That doesn't *create* outlets/actions, only offers another way to *connect* them.