# Where to add Class Outlets in design view in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

Am looking how to add Class Outlets to the design view (formerly Interface Builder) in Xcode 4, and can't seem to find where they are.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: class outlets? you mean `IBOutlet`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was answered here:

[How to define Outlets and Actions in the Classes Pane in Interface Builder in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127121/how-to-define-outlets-and-actions-in-the-classes-pane-in-interface-builder-in-xco)